# I want to use a selected part of a string

Tags: c#, string

Lets say i have a string path that looks like this: `C:/users/name/epicEnding`

And i want to just use the last part of the path: `epicEnding`

How can i always use the last part of the path without just writing `string endPath = "epicEnding";` (sorry, dont know another way to describe it.)

And the results should be:

`//selected path: "C:/users/name/epicEnding"`
ex. `//last part: "epicEnding"`

(it should be the last part of the path whatever the path looks like.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, all you slashes are seemingly the wrong way. However, assuming this is a windows path you could use

[Path.GetFileName Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns the file name and extension of the specified path string.

**Example**

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", fileName, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", path, result);

// This code produces output similar to the following:
//
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\myfile.ext') returns 'myfile.ext'
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\') returns ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] arrParts = @"C:/users/name/epicEnding".Split('//');

Console.Print(arrParts[arrParts.Length-1]);
```

If it is a FileName you want (I am not sure as there is no file extension) use @TheGeneral answer. Otherwise if its a part of the path this answer will be useful.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the fast answers! :) makes me happy! I will try both of your answers!

Answer (score 0):

In response to @TheGeneral: if this is indeed a windows filename, you can also use Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)

this will remove the file extension (.exe, .docx, .xlsx, ...) for you, leaving the clean name as seen inside of the folder